# Black/Gray/Rainbow screen once GPU load decreases

Tags: freeze, nvidia-geforce

While playing the latest games, I frequently get black/gray/rainbow screens. Those freezes occure right after the heavy load of the game has stopped. So for example, when I quit the game, I get the freeze. When the game loads a new level and there is nothing to calculate for the GPU, I get the freeze. Whenever the load stops, I get the freeze.

I tried to run FurMark. I runs just fine for, like, any time at 100% GPU usage and max temperature without problems. Once I stop the benchmark, the PC freezes.

My specs:
AMD FX-6350, 
Asus Geforce GTX 770, 
8GB RAM, 
Asus M5A97 EVO R2.0

I have the latest Geforce drivers installed through the Geforce Experience tool and I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Any ideas what might cause this behavior? At first I thought about a weak PSU, but under heavy load, I don't have any issues, only when the load stops... Might it be the sudden temperature change when the loads stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question so that everybody who has the same issue will know how I solved it.

What I have done first is to check if there is a firmware update available from ASUS for the GPU. Yes there was. I installed it via their Live Update tool. It seems to have fixed the issue. I have been playing 4 times now without issues. Also the benchmark now runs and I can close it without issues. The firmware update seems to have solved the issue.

So if you experience the same issue. Check for a firmware update first!

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the drivers and install them via [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com) website, I had problems before with faulty drivers from the GeForce experience program. How heavy is the load on your CPU?

Comment: will try reinstalling the drivers. In the benchmark for example, the CPU load is ~40%. Not an issue I would think, right?

Comment: Should not be an issue at all. I have ran 60-80% running BF3, I have a  MSI 790FX-GD70 with a AMD PhenomIIx4 3.2 stock, 16Gb Ram, and a GTX750 TI FTW. I have had things go wrong with the GeForce experience and wondered why but havent found a reason. I hope that work around helps. Post back and let us know.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the Geforce Experience. What I have done first is to check if there is a firmware update available from ASUS for the GPU. Yes there was. I installed it via their Live Update tool.

It seems to have fixed the issue. I have been playing 4 times now without issues. Also the benchmark now runs and I can close it without issues. The firmware update seems to have solved the issue.